# Итерация с помощью цикла for по объектам keyvaluepair

Tags: c#

У меня есть список `List<KeyValuePair> someList`. 
Можно ли для итерации и изменения определенный элементов списка использовать цикл for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно, а в чём собственно проблема?

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(){
             new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1,"one"), 
             new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "two")
         };
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i].Key; // Key 1,2
    list[i].Value; // Value "one", "two"
    list[i].Key = 42; // Error
    list[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(42, "42"); // OK
}
```